# How to copy a Number column to VARCHAR column with leading and trailing zeros

Tags: oracle10g

I am trying to copy Number column to VARCHAR column but its removing leading and trailing zeros. I tried with below update SQL.

```
UPDATE Employee  SET Salary_char = TO_CHAR(salary_num);
```

But its removing leading and trailing zeros. if value is 0.20 it persists .2 
How to avoid this.

Comment: 0.20 and .2 are the same number. If you want to have a specific format in the string version then you need to supply that as the second argument to `to_char()`. You will need a fixed number of leading and trailing zeros though - do you only want the leading zero if the value is less than 1? And always two decimal places?

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide a suitable [number format model](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements004.htm#i34570) for your call to `to_char()`, e.g.

```
UPDATE Employee SET Salary_char = TO_CHAR(salary, '9999990.00')
```

with enough leading 9s to allow the highest value you can have in the original column.

Comment: select TO_CHAR(99.0, '9999990.00') from dual returning 99.00 but i want value as it is i.e. 99.0 in this case .

Comment: You want 99 to become 99.0, but 99.9 to become 99.90? That seems very unusual. If you're formatting a currency amount you'd norally want a fixed number of decimal places. What about 99.99? Does that stay as it is or become 99.990? etc.

Comment: Also I think maybe you're confused. In your previous comment the first argument to `to_char()` is a **number**. It doesn't matter if you write that as 99, 99.0, 99.00, 0099.000 or whatever in your statement. It is purely a number. Wanting it "as it is" doesn't mean anything. The salary values in your table are also just numbers. Your client may be showing them as formatted strings when you query the table and it displays the results, but that is invisible to the actual statements you run.

Comment: Column Salary i have just use as example. its some other sensitive number and i want it as it is from number column with leading trailing zeros. if it has value as 0.30 it should be same in new VARCHAR column.

Answer (score 0):

Below update worked for me. It update number column values as it is in varchar column.

```
UPDATE Employee  SET Salary_char = TO_NUMBER(salary_num);
```